# Can't draw a overlap2d scene

Tags: java, libgdx, overlap2d

I'm starting with libGDX and overlap2d, I'm following this tutorial: [Runtime Quick Start - Overlap2D setup tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Qmkfw2svs0). I did everything like the video shows, but when I try to run it, some red lines appear. I don't have any idea about what I could do to solve. Can any one help me?

Here's my console:  [image]

---

Here's my Main class:
[image]

---

Hers my GameStage class:
[image]

---

project.dt:
{"pixelToWorld":3,"originalResolution":{"name":"orig","width":1920,"height":1200},"scenes":[{"sceneName":"MainScene","physicsPropertiesVO":{}}]}

---

MainScene.dt:
{"sceneName":"MainScene","composite":{"sImages":[{"uniqueId":3,"tags":[],"x":-7.666664,"y":-13,"originX":85.333336,"originY":85.333336,"layerName":"Default","imageName":"chao"},{"uniqueId":4,"tags":[],"x":159.33334,"y":-10.333336,"originX":85.333336,"originY":85.333336,"zIndex":1,"layerName":"Default","imageName":"chao"},{"uniqueId":5,"tags":[],"x":-7.3333282,"y":157.66666,"originX":85.333336,"originY":85.333336,"zIndex":2,"layerName":"Default","imageName":"chao"},{"uniqueId":6,"tags":[],"x":159.33333,"y":158.66667,"originX":85.333336,"originY":85.333336,"zIndex":3,"layerName":"Default","imageName":"chao"}],"layers":[{"layerName":"Default","isVisible":true}]},"lightSystemEnabled":true,"ambientColor":[0,0,0,1],"physicsPropertiesVO":{}}

---

Does anyone have any idea how can I solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that method `loadScene(MainScene.dt)` is looking for a `pixelToWorld` field but there is no `pixelToWorld` in your `MainScene.dt` file.

Possible reason may be Overlap2d Editor and overlap2d-runtime version incompatibility.

Comment: And the run time I don't know where it is

Comment: find it in your root build.gradle file

Comment: compile "com.underwaterapps.overlap2druntime:overlap2d-runtime-libgdx:0.1.1"

Comment: please show your `project.dt` and `MainScene.dt` file

Comment: It's on the question now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143000/discussion-between-lucas-gaspar-and-abhishek-aryan).

Comment: Nope, I don't know what is happening

Comment: Have you installed IntellijIDEA ?

Comment: I did install android studio

Comment: Okay then, Have you imported your project in Android Studio through gradle.

Comment: Yes. When I just run it it works, but when I try to instantiate a SceneLoader, it breakes

Comment: `compile "com.underwaterapps.overlap2druntime:overlap2d-runtime-libgdx:0.1.1` and this is the jar your using in build.gradle file